# How to tell whether the URL is an image?(When extension doesn't reveal anything)

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently building an AJAX call to fetch the data from an API(of which the data structure is pretty messy). The problem is that one AJAX call can return as many as 30 elements in the array and some of the image URLs don't reveal file extension and can potentially lead to another external source(not image). All the images won't be appended to DOM until they are downloaded via **promise** so one failure to load the image will reject the entire **Promise.all()**. Is there any way to tell whether an URL is an image when file extension isn't available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an ajax request and check the header **content-type** to be as "**image/jpeg**". The following demo will request a picture from a url and will log on console the value of that attribute:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.onreadystatechange = function(){ console.log(this.getResponseHeader('content-type')) };
x.open('GET', 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/cors-caron-boardwalk-across-bog-near-tregaron-wales-62354242.jpg', true);
x.send();
```

The hard part was finding a picture hosted on a web site that was friendly with its CORS policy.

Comment: I was trying to test it on this URL(https://www.northguan-nsa.gov.tw/user/Article.aspx?Lang=1&SNo=04005325) but it showed the error of "Ensure CORS response header values are valid". As it turns out, there is no such header as "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" on the response. Is there anything I can do on the frontend?